# How to show a message in Sweet Alert after the execution of a submit button in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, sweetalert

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project. In my view, I have two submit type buttons, with different actions on both.

What I want is to implement an alert that notifies me when it has successfully processed the data.

I show the part of my view where I have these buttons.

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="submit" value="Vista Previa" class="btn btn-success" />
                        <input type="submit" onclick="mostrarAlerta()" value="Procesar Datos" class="btn btn-secondary" formaction="/File/CargarSQLServer" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the submit "Procesar Datos" button, where I upload to a database. At the end of that load I would like to show an alert that only notifies me that the data has been processed, without any button inside that alert.

I have the following function where I show my alert.

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
    function mostrarAlerta() {
        swal({
            title: "Actualización Exitosa",
            text: "Procesamiento de datos realizado correctamente",
            icon: "success",
            button: false
        });
    };
</script>
}
```

My problem is that the alert is displayed when I press the submit button, and disappears when I finish uploading to my database.

I would like to know if there is a way to get this alert to show up after the data load and stay for at least about 4 seconds. What properties should I use?

In advance thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

use the "setTimeout" function in JavaScript to display Alert after of time

```
function mostrarAlerta() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        swal({
            title: "Actualización Exitosa",
            text: "Procesamiento de datos realizado correctamente",
            icon: "success",
            button: false,
            timer: 4000
        });
    }, 2000);
};
```

the alert will be displayed after 2 seconds, it's will remain on the screen for 4 seconds

Comment: I have tried with your suggestion, it does not show me the alert at any time.

Comment: will need to include the library that contains the "swal" function in your code
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
`